# Disable ViewPager scrolling when specific child has focus

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesturedetector

I know there are several answers which describe how to lock a `ViewPager`.

But I want that my `ViewPager` is able to scroll only if the touch doesn't occour on a specific child.

So how can I "filter" out which child views are touched?

example code of how I want to lock my `ViewPager`:

```
for (Integer resource:mResources) {
        if(resource.intValue()==view.getId()){
            touchTriggeredOnView(view.getId());
        }
    }
```

The reason why I want to do this is, that I have a custom view which needs to detect fling gestures.
This custom view is a child of a `Fragment` and the `Fragment` is a child of the `ViewPager`.

So: `ViewPager`->`Fragment`->`CustomView`.

I'm able to detect the `DOWN` but not the `FLING` event inside my `CustomView`.

I think that the `ViewPager` captures the `FLING` event --> bad thing.

I hope that my question is clear enough.

Comment: How you resolved it? I have a same problem

Comment: @Menu The accepted answer was the solution.

Comment: so is it possible to lock view pager events only for specific area of the page ?? @Appyx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[onTouch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) and [gesture listeners](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) in Android have boolean return values which indicate whether event (touch, fling, click) is consumed or not.

ViewPager probably consumes "Fling" event, however you could override onTouch, gesture listener in ViewPager and return false - thus not consuming touch event and passing it to your custom view.